# Cleaner git remote urls

Tags: git, gitweb

I'm attempting to run my own git server with gitweb as the web interface. I'm serving up a directory called 'git/' here: `/Users/me/Sites/git`, which is the document root for `git.example.com`

I've created a user on my mac named 'git', such that I can ssh git@git.example.com, and I am logged in ok.

Now, say I'm working as 'me@example.com' (the user), and I want to push to my remote @ git.example.com, I have to type in `git remote add gitweb ssh://git@git.example.com/~/Sites/git/projectname.git`

Is there any way I can remove the `~/Sites/git/` from the url? Ideally, I want to be able to type: `git remote add gitweb ssh://git@git.example.com/projectname.git`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GitWeb and ssh is for two different Git access mechanism:

- Gitweb would be served by an Apache http server: see my [`httpd.conf`](https://github.com/VonC/compileEverything/blob/master/apache/env.conf.tpl#L49-L60) as an example. But it isn't for cloning, only for browsing.
- an http(s) access would require [this config](https://github.com/VonC/compileEverything/blob/master/apache/env.conf.tpl#L95), with an alias calling the `git-http-backend` (in my example, I call `gitolite-shell` because I want to benefit from the [authorization layer which is Gitolite](http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/auth.html))
- an ssh access is through the ssh daemon (no need for a git daemon here, plus the git protocol cannot be used for pushing), and will necessitate the full path.

The only case where ssh doesn't need the full path to execute your clone/push/pull command is when it is using the [ssh **forced command** mechanism](http://oreilly.com/catalog/sshtdg/chapter/ch08.html#22858) in order to intercept your git command and call a custom script (which can transform your "`projectname.git`" into a "`~/Sites/git/projectname.git`").
That is what [Gitolite](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite) does, for instance.

Answer (score 1):

you can leverage git deamon 's --base-path, e.g.
I share a git repo1 under /home/fengxx/gitdemo/ in 192.168.52.2

```
git daemon --verbose --export-all --base-path=/home/fengxx/gitdemo/
```

and in another pc, I can run

```
git clone git://192.168.52.2/repo1
```

if I have to use ssh
the URL will be ~/gitdemo/repo1

```
git clone ssh://fengxx@192.168.52.2/~/gitdemo/repo1
```

And you can set user.name by

```
git config --global user.name yourlogin
```